# How to use composable computed value?

Tags: vuejs3, computed-properties, composable

I'm trying to create something like service in Vue3.
My app will be embedded in windows native (WinAPI) application which is passing me configuration (api-url and other stuff) in the URL query parameters. URL like `?action=hide-keyboard&api-url=server.com:port/api/v1`

Wrote something like:

```
//QueryString.js
<script>
import {computed, reactive, ref} from 'vue';

export function useQueryString() {
  let query = reactive(ref({}));
  return computed({
    get: () => {
      query = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search))
      console.log('computed:get:', query)
    },
    set: (v) => {
      window.location.search = new URLSearchParams({...query, ...v}).toString()
      console.log('computed:set:', v)
    }
  });
  }
</script>
```

and using this like:

```
import useQueryString from "../composables/QueryString.vue";
[...]
  mounted() {
    fetch(`http://${useQueryString['api-url']}/places/endpoint`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if(!!data.errorCode) this.error = {message: data.message, code: data.errorCode}
        else this.places = data;
      });
  },
[...]
```

But the `fetch` above calls `http://undefined/places/endpoints`
What I'm doing wrong? Expecting to fetch `http://server.com:port/api/v1/places/endpoints`

Comment: It seems you intended to use computed property 'api-url', but there isn't such thing in your `QueryString.js`. might be a mistake?